# How to capture image and record video using GPUImage 2?

Tags: ios, swift3, camera, gpuimage, gpuimagestillcamera

How to capture image with applied filter using GPUImage? For reference, below is the code which I am calling for get image:

```
func countdownFinished(_ view: LUCountdownView!) {
    let pictureOutput = PictureOutput()
    pictureOutput.keepImageAroundForSynchronousCapture = true
    pictureOutput.encodedImageFormat = .png
    pictureOutput.synchronousImageCapture()
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'click image and record video'?

Comment: @季亨达 i meant how to capture image and video

Comment: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage this demo is not working for you?if working then what error you are getting.

Comment: @BHAVIKPANCHAL i think you didn't read my question Properly , i want to capture image, but using to swift library of GPUimage , for reference you can check this URL https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2